# display email one by one using explode and foreach

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I'm try to display email address in loop one by one. But, it is simply printing all the email address in single line.

**email.txt**

"firstemail","secondemail","thirdemail","fourthemail","fifthemail"

**email.php**

```
<?php 
$count=1;
$emails=readfile("../email.txt");
$email=explode(",",$emails);
foreach($email as $e){
    echo "$count Email : $e<br />\n";
$count=$count+1;
}
?>
```

**Expected Output**

"firstemail"

"secondemail"

"thirdemail"

"fourthemail"

"fifthemail"

But, I'm getting

"firstemail","secondemail","thirdemail","fourthemail","fifthemail"

Comment: btw: missing a $ in line 4 explode (",", $emails);

Comment: this is the only code, I have right now.

Comment: @Casper changed but still same issue.

Comment: are you creating aweb page or text file?

Comment: web page ? why ? no.. I'm just trying to print email address line by line from `email.txt` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's basically what [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) does; it reads the file and outputs it. The return value is  how many bytes were read (which I don't see in your output).

I'll admit that it's a pretty bad name for such a function but that's the fun stuff you will see when developing in PHP :-)

In any case, the function you're looking for is [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$emails = file_get_contents("../email.txt");
```

**Update**

It seems to me that you're actually looking for [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv):

```
$f = fopen('../email.txt', 'rt');
while (!feof($f)) {
    $row = fgetcsv($f);
    if ($row == false || $row[0] === null) {
        continue;
    }
    // $row is an array comprising the email addresses on one line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like below:

```
<?php 
$count=1;
$emails= file_get_contents("../email.txt");
$email=explode(",",$emails);
foreach($email as $e){
    echo "$count Email : $e<br />\n";
$count=$count+1;
}
?>
```

Output:
1 Email : "firstemail"
2 Email : "secondemail"
3 Email : "thirdemail"
4 Email : "fourthemail"
5 Email : "fifthemail"

Answer (score 0):

Well the shown code does not correspond to the output you are mentioning...

This code snippet assumes you do not need the numbering, but instead just want an e-mail address in each line.
But a correct code snippet would be something like:

```
<?php
if (file_exists('../email.txt'))
{
   $file_contents = file_get_contents('../email.txt');
   $emails = explode(',', $file_contents);
   foreach ($emails as $e)
   {
      echo $e."<br>\n";
   }
}
else
{ 
   echo 'file does not exist!';
}
?>
```